# moment.js doesn't add hours correctly to the time given

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Here is my JS:

```
var startDateTime = '2021-10-19 20:00:00';
var endDateTime = moment(startDateTime).add(2, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
  
document.getElementById("startDateTime").innerHTML = startDateTime;
document.getElementById("endDateTime").innerHTML = endDateTime;
```

I'm expecting `endDateTime` to be `2021-10-19 22:00:00`. But it comes out as `2021-10-19 10:00:00` instead. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0L3zyqxs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try H as below this is for 24 hours

```
var endDateTime = moment(startDateTime)
    .add(2, 'hours')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Ah. Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To use 24h format in moment.js you need to use HH.

```
var endDateTime = moment(startDateTime).add(2, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!